# discord py - message.mentions "else" makes nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get the user that was mentioned in a message and send him a private message. That's working without problems, but now I want to add a message for the case, that the mentioned member is not on the same server.

I searched a lot and try now for over 3 hours to find a solution.

**Showcase of the problem:** https://youtu.be/PYZMVXYtxpE

Heres my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
 if len(message.mentions) == 1:
   membe1 = message.mentions[0].id
   membe2 = bot.get_user(membe1)
   guild = bot.get_guild(message.author.guild.id)
   if guild.get_member(membe1) is not None:
      await membe2.send(content=f"you was mentioned in the server chat")
   else:
      embed2 = discord.Embed(title=f"» :warning: | PING not possible", description=f"not possible")
      await message.channel.send(content=f"{message.author.mention}", embed=embed)
      await message.delete()
      return
```

The first part is working without problems, but at the "`else`" part, does the bot nothing. He still posts the message with the "invalid" ping in the chat and just ignores it. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Could you send a screenshot of the output from the bot?

Comment: No errors, nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error of design in what you are trying to do.
In Discord, you are not able to **mention** a **user** if he is not on that same server, so what you are checking will never work at all, currently your code is pretty much checking if the mentioned user exists, which will always happen unless he leaves the guild at the same time the command is executed.

Say for example, to make your command work you want to mention the user *user123*, who is in your server, you do the following:

> @user123 blablabla

And that works because Discord internal cache can find *user123* in your server and it is **mentioned**, which means that clicking on "@user123" will show us a target with his avatar, his roles or whatsoever.

But if you try to do the same for an *invalid user*, let's say *notuser321*:

> @notuser321 blablabla

This is not a mention, take for example that you know who *notuser321* is but he is in the same server as the bot is. Discord cannot retrieve this **user** from the cache and it is not considered a **mention**, just a single **string**, so not a single part of your code will be triggered, because `len(message.mentions)` will be `0`.

Something that you could try would be using [**regular expressions**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find an attempt to tag within `message.content`. An example would be something like this:

```
import re

message = "I love @user1 and @user2"
mention_attempt = re.findall(r'[@]\S*', message)   # ['@user1', '@user2']
```

Comment: I got the error: `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
` for `if mention_attempt in message.content:`

Comment: `re.findall()` returns a list with all the results that if found, either check only `mention_attempt[0]` or iterate over its elements to send a message to each user mentioned.

Comment: You should try to debug your code to see why you are getting that. It basically means that it does not identify any syntax like _@username_ within your message. You gotta pass the `message.content` to the `re.findall()` function, not the `message` object...